# Average sum ignoring max or min

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use AVG to get the average of some values, but ignoring the max and min values only if they are 1.5 bellow or above the second max and min values. I will put some examples:

Example 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 100.5 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 101.5 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 103.1 v FROM DUAL ) D
```

I need this result, ignoring the 103.1 value:

```
100.5
101.5
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 100.5 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 101.5 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 103.1 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 106.2 v FROM DUAL) D
```

I need this result, ignoring only the 106.2 value:

```
100.5
101.1
103.1
```

Example 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 100.0 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 102.0 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 103.0 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 105.0 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 107.0 v FROM DUAL) D
```

I need this result, ignoring 100.0 and 107.0 values:

```
102.0
103.0
105.0
```

When there is only two values it doesnt matter.
With the right result, I can AVG(value) correctly.

Comment: So - if you have two values tied for highest (or lowest) that automatically means they must be included in the calculation, and not discarded, right? Then: if you have only one input value, there is nothing to discard. If you have TWO values and they are more than 1.5 apart, then both most be EXCLUDED, and the average is then NULL - is all of that correct?

Comment: @mathguy kuddos

Comment: @mathguy I put some examples. You are right, except the case only there only two values and they are more than 1.5 apart. In this case, they must not be excluded

Comment: @Killer - what version of Oracle are you using? (As reported by running `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION` in your session.) All of the different formulations of your problem can be easily solved with the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause, but that is only available since version 12.1.

Comment: @mathguy Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I would like to know why it gets -1, implying that my question is not clear or useful :(

Comment: @Killer - it's Stack Overflow. Just get used to the fact that there are a lot of jerks, incompetents, etc. on the site; it is not moderated (not in certain aspects anyway). Get the help you need on the site, enjoy the contributions from some excellent experts who volunteer their time here, and don't worry about up and down votes. Use yours wisely, but don't pay any attention to down votes that are not accompanied by an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a combination of analytic functions (lead/lag) and conditional aggregation. Here's what I came up with. Note that I allow for multiple groups, the "adjusted" average must be computed for each group separately (a common task in statistics when you must throw out the outliers in each group, when they exist):

```
with
     inputs ( id, val ) as (
       select 101, 33   from dual union all
       select 102, 23   from dual union all
       select 102, 22.8 from dual union all
       select 103, 30   from dual union all
       select 103, 40   from dual union all
       select 104, 90   from dual union all
       select 104, 92   from dual union all
       select 104, 92   from dual union all
       select 104, 91.5 from dual union all
       select 104, 91.7 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select    id, 
          avg ( case when cnt >= 3 
                        and ( lag_val is null and lead_val - val >= 1.5 
                              or
                              lead_val is null and val - lag_val >= 1.5
                            )
                     then null
                     else val
                end
              ) as adjusted_avg_val
from      (
            select id, val, count(val) over (partition by id) as cnt,
                   lag  ( val ) over ( partition by id order by val ) as lag_val,
                   lead ( val ) over ( partition by id order by val ) as lead_val
            from   inputs
          )
group by id
;
```

**Output**:

```
 ID  ADJUSTED_AVG_VAL
---  ----------------
101                33
102              22.9
103                35                      
104              91.8
```

Comment: Okay, I can see that there is a lot of things that I must learn yet. Thanks, it worked like a charm. I tested all the cases and it is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro I must thank you, when I post a question here, I always try to understand the answers and not only "copy and paste" what you guys brings here. Thank you.

Comment: @killer I just woke up in a sarcastic mood mate! Don't get me wrong ok? Have a great day :)

Comment: @Killer - if you want to see how the code works, here is one strategy that will help (if you are not using it already). Run just the subquery by itself, to see what the output is. Try to understand that - to see how LEAD and LAG work, why there are NULLs in those columns (for the obvious reason: there is no "preceding" value when you look at the first row, etc.) Then run the outer query, but without the GROUP BY - just with the CASE expression in the SELECT, not wrapped within AVG. Look at the result again and understand what the CASE expression does. Then the aggregation is easy.

Comment: @mathguy I dont remember if you asked me this, but, when there is two identical values, one must not be excluded. I.E. 180, 180, 181 has 180.5 as a result.

Comment: @killer - I asked you this question, I said in that case it doesn't make sense to exclude EITHER of the two values. Your answer was that everything I said was CORRECT (including this, then) - EXCEPT the case of exactly two values, which are more than 1.5 apart. This requirement is indeed different from what I solved for, and in statistics it doesn't make sense; the difference between the highest and second-highest values is ZERO. (Also in the example you gave all numbers are within 1.0 of each other, so why is ANYTHING excluded?)

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstand your questions. I will try to answer again the question with more accurate infos.

Comment: @Killer - no reason to be sorry for anything, no worries mate. Rather: assuming you didn't make up the requirements, but instead you have a business user (a scientist or analyst of some sort?) and they give it to you... go back to them and ask them to confirm that if the inputs are like 100, 100, 81, 80.5, 80, they want to throw away ONE of the 100 values. That doesn't make sense in statistics (I should know, I am a mathematician and I know a lot more about statistics than anything having to do with programming.) If the values are 100, 99.99, 81, 80.5, 80, then nothing is discarded.

Comment: @Killer  So if the second highest value changes from 99.99 to 100, why should one of the two 100 values be discarded? If 99.99 changes to 100.01, again ALL values are included and nothing is discarded. After you can confirm the requirement one way or the other, I will work on an Oracle 12 solution. Good luck mate!

Comment: I must agree with you. But, in that case of 180, 180 and 181, there is no difference in 1.5 (why 180 would be discarded?). But, you are right. Im doing some job to a gelatine laboratory and they to get the bloom, odour and other things. Im going to ask then this particular question.

Comment: @mathguy FYI, I schedule a reunion with the users from the lab to get all those answers about two identical values in the "edge" and another questions that I have in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @Killer - Sure - feel free to come back after that meeting.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following combination of `row_number` `lead` and `lag`

```
with cte as (
SELECT 100.5 v FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101.5 v FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103.1 v FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 106.2 v FROM DUAL)
-- end of sample data
select avg(v)
from
(
  select row_number() over (order by v desc) arn, 
         row_number() over (order by v) drn, 
         lag(v) over (order by v) av,
         lead(v) over (order by v) dv,
         v
  from cte
) t
where (arn != 1 and drn != 1) or        -- if they are no maximum nor minumum
        (drn = 1 and v + 1.5 > dv) or   -- if they are minimum
        (arn = 1 and v - 1.5 < av) or   -- if they are maximum
        (av is null and arn < 3) or     -- if there are just two ore one value
        (dv is null and drn < 3)        -- if there are just two ore one value
```

Comment: Almost there. Please note, though: (1) if there are either exactly one value, or two values more than 1.5 apart, your query will compute the average over zero rows (no rows will pass the WHERE conditions); (2) if you can avoid ordering by v, both ascending and descending, that is better; Oracle is not smart enough to use the same ordering to assign both row numbers, and instead it will do the ordering twice. Better to take advantage of lead or lag being NULL (they play the same role as your row numbers being 1).

Comment: Almost. It really worked but, as @mathguy said, when there are two values and they are 1.5 apart, it brings me zero rows.

Comment: @killer however, if you have one value then it is not satisfying your condition and it should be ignored, the same for two values being more than 1.5 apart.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the second suggestion, it is much prettier now

Comment: @killer I just post the examples. This one correctly compute the average from two values: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7fd48a90bd9851f4df4bcf705ee55d7b and this one correctly does not: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=15f2a9724ab5f4832798582008edcec3 what is wrong with that?

Comment: @RadimBača - you still didn't address the first issue. Please see the exchange of Comments under the OP's initial question. If there are exactly two values, then their average must be calculated REGARDLESS of the "difference of 1.5 or more" condition; that condition should come into play only when there are three or more values to take the average of. This is why I included an analytic count in my solution.

Comment: @Killer ok, I have returned to my original solution using `row_numbers` and included a condition covering the case with two or one value. best.

Comment: @RadimBača now it is working, but I think that instead of avg(*) there would be avg(v). I will take a look into that, considering what mathguy has said until now

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you simply just need to express the result, so ...

```
WITH D as(
SELECT  100.0 v FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 102.0 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 103.0 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 105.0 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 107.0 FROM DUAL)
SELECT  avg(v)
FROM D
where (v < (select max(v) from D )
       and ((select max(v) from D )
            -(select max(v) from D where v != 
              (select max(v) from D ) ) > 1.5))
or
(v > (select min(v) from D )
       and ((select min(v) from D )
            +(select min(v) from D where v != 
              (select min(v) from D ) ) > 1.5))
```

... should do the trick!

But thinking ahead... the below version may also be useful ;)

```
  WITH D as(
    SELECT 1 PK, 100.0 v FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1,102.0 FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1,103.0 FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1,105.0 FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1,107.0 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT  PK,avg(v)
    FROM D
    where (v < (select max(v) from D group by PK)
           and ((select max(v) from D group by PK)
                -(select max(v) from D where v != 
                  (select max(v) from D group by PK) group by PK) > 1.5))
    or
    (v > (select min(v) from D group by PK)
           and ((select min(v) from D group by PK)
                +(select min(v) from D where v != 
                  (select min(v) from D group by PK) group by PK) > 1.5))

    GROUP BY PK
```

In real life though you would consider the execution plans of the above in a large dataset too (homework).

For any further clarifications, I am at your disposal via comments.

Sincerely, 
Ted

Comment: When there are only two values and they are within 1.5 (i.e. 181 and 182) it only result in 182.

Comment: Your query doesn't do what the OP requested. Just replace ALL your input values with 100 (they are all equal) and see what happens.

Comment: You can't simply compare to MAX and MIN, if the problem requires different handling when the MAX or MIN is unique, vs. when they are reached more than once.

Comment: @mathguy why we doing this again?! (thinking aloud). Help me out a little be more constructively ?! (just a suggestion, no obligation whatsoever ;)

Comment: @mathguy ignore my last comment, I see what you did ;)

Comment: I was ignoring it already, no worries mate! My second comment was not repeating the first. Rather, since you said you were "on it", I was suggesting that fixing the query will require rethinking it, for the reason I gave. Cheers!

Comment: @mathguy honestly now, you found a great solution. it's just my greek sarcastic mood and I practice British humour. You won this one for sure, but I gave some laughs too, I'll take the cheers for that ;)